# Insert new data into sqlite if not present

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to figure out if it is possible, how do I automatically insert the year on when I open the class for the first time. In practice, if the class does not find what it is the year 2014 has become part of the column year 2014, if it is present, do not enter.
My database and thus created:
@

```
Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE "+TURNI+" ("+TURNI_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+DATA+" NUMERIC,"+MESE+" TEXT,"+ANNO+" NUMERIC)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
```

I need to insert the year on the variation in use if there is no
    @Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_turni);

```
    turniList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List);

    mHelper = new DbHelper(this);

    //aggiunta nuovi record
    findViewById(R.id.anno_txt).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Set_anno.class);
            String mese="Gennaio  ";
            String Mese=getPackageName();
               i.putExtra(Mese+".Intmese", mese);
            i.putExtra("update", false);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    //click aggiorna dati
    turniList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {


            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    Aggiungi_turni.class);
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            String anno = prefs.getString(ANNO, Integer.toString(year));

            String mese="Gennaio  ";
            String Mese=getPackageName();
            i.putExtra(Mese+".Intmese", mese);
            i.putExtra("Anno", anno);
            i.putExtra("Mese", turni_mese.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("Turno", turni_turno.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("Ore", turni_ore.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("Notes", turni_notes.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("ID", turni_Id.get(arg2));
            i.putExtra("update", true);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    //click lungo cancellazione record
    turniList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                final int arg2, long arg3) {

            build = new AlertDialog.Builder(Gennaio.this);
            build.setTitle("Cancella " + turni_mese.get(arg2)+ " "
                    + turni_turno.get(arg2)+ " "
                    + turni_ore.get(arg2)+ ""+
                    turni_notes.get(arg2));
            build.setMessage("Vuoi cancellarlo ?");
            build.setPositiveButton("Si",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {

                            Toast.makeText(
                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                    turni_mese.get(arg2)
                                            + turni_turno.get(arg2)
                                            + turni_ore.get(arg2)
                                            + turni_notes.get(arg2)
                                            + "è stato cancellato.", 3000).show();

                            dataBase.delete(
                                    DbHelper.TURNI,
                                    DbHelper.TURNI_ID + "="
                                            + turni_Id.get(arg2), null);
                            displayData();
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            build.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = build.create();
            alert.show();

            return true;
        }
    });
    }


@Override
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_tutti);

        tuttiList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.List);

        mHelper = new DbHelper(this);

        //aggiunta nuovi record
        findViewById(R.id.anno_txt).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Set_anno.class);
                String mese="Gennaio  ";
                String Mese=getPackageName();
                   i.putExtra(Mese+".Intmese", mese);
                i.putExtra("update", false);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        //click aggiorna dati
        tuttiList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {


                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Aggiungi_turni.class);
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                String anno = prefs.getString(ANNO, Integer.toString(year));

                String mese="Gennaio  ";
                String Mese=getPackageName();
                i.putExtra(Mese+".Intmese", mese);
                i.putExtra("Anno", anno);
                i.putExtra("Mese", giorni_mese.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("ID", giorni_Id.get(arg2));
                i.putExtra("update", true);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });


        }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        displayData();
        super.onResume();
    }

    /**
     * Visualizza dati da SQLite
     */
    private void displayData() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        String anno = prefs.getString(ANNO, Integer.toString(year));

        TextView textanni = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.anno_txt);
        textanni.setText("Gennaio  "+anno);
        int anni = Integer.parseInt(anno);      

        dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Calendar mycal = new GregorianCalendar(anni, Calendar.JANUARY, 1);
        int giorni = mycal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int dayOfWeak = mycal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

        switch (dayOfWeak) {
            case Calendar.SUNDAY:
                break;
            case Calendar.MONDAY:
                break;
            case Calendar.TUESDAY:
                break;
            case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
                break;
            case Calendar.THURSDAY:
                break;
            case Calendar.FRIDAY:
                break;
            case Calendar.SATURDAY:
                break;     

        }
```

Comment: I need to figure out if it's possible to have such a column name: **update**

Comment: I don't understand your question, please try to better explain the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: UPDATE is a SQLITE (and all of the SQL compliant RDBMS) **reserved keyword**: http://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: Please be more explicit in your question and do not post the full activity code if it does not concern the question. You want to add an element in the database if it is not present?

Comment: Not only that, but there are some other issues with the code, e.g. `Toast` doesn't accept duration in millisecond for the 3rd parameter.

Comment: I need to insert the year on the variation in use if there is no

Answer (score 0):

As a pre-check, if all you need to store is a single value (without entity structure) I'd rather use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for this matter.

I'm afraid that in both cases, SharedPreferences and SQLite, you'll need to retrieve the value of a key or table before knowing if it's present or not. In case it helps, note that insertWithOnConflict() and update()/updateWithOnConflict methods within [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) return the id of newly inserted or existing row id or -1 in case of error, and the number of rows updated respectively. That may help you to know if your inserts or updates had any impact on your data model without performing another request.